# Laravel and Angular Real Time Application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, laravel, socket.io

My assignment is to create a realtime application using Laravel and AngularJs. I have gone through some blogs and youtube videos. But i am not able to decide what are the exact technologies i should use.

I have created REST API in Laravel and frontend in AngularJs. There are some modules in the application which requires data should be realtime.

Example : There is a job listing page having status property, This status should be automatically changed if the status of job is updated by someone else.

Suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This isn't a good question because it's largely opinionated.  There are a few ways this can be done though.  Using websockets is probably your best bet.  You can also check out pusher.com or the technique called long-polling.  This tut might also help: https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: i am not sure you have understood the question. By the way thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 5.1 there is an option to use pusher,which is works like as socket.Using this i did an realtime chatting application.See the video it will help you to make sense how will you go
https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1